# Adicionar TextBox dentro de uma table HTML com JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o Script JQuery abaixo que pesquisa um Material e retorna uma lista em Json desse materiais, eu preciso colocar esses dados em uma tabela e colocar um campo para que o usuário digite a quantidade desses materiais, mesmo colocando no Script para que o textbox fique com o tamanho 2 ele continuo no tamanho normal. Alguem sabe como posso fazer isso?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#pesquisar').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/RCM/ListarMateriais",
            type: "POST",
            data: { nome: $('#NomeMaterial').val() },
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (I, item) {
                    $('#tbl').append("<tr><td>" + item.Nome + "</td><td>" + item.TD + "</td><td>" + item.Unidade +
                        "</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"qtd\" size=\"2\" /> <input id=\"btAdd\" type=\"button\" value=\"Adicionar\" /> </td>")
                })
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho que você quis dizer `width`, não `size`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#pesquisar').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/RCM/ListarMateriais",
            type: "POST",
            data: { nome: $('#NomeMaterial').val() },
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (I, item) {
                    $('#tbl').append("<tr><td>" + item.Nome + "</td><td>" + item.TD + "</td><td>" + item.Unidade +
                        "</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"qtd\" style=\"width: 50px;\" /> <input id=\"btAdd\" type=\"button\" value=\"Adicionar\" /> </td>")
                })
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Assim funcionou, muito obrigado Cigano, me ajudando mais uma vez.